# Button holding latitude and longitude, and been grab to the next page?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I`m trying to make an application that can provide location for some places by clicking a button. 
Right now what my button can do only bring me to another which is maps page that been set with longitude and latitude. (2.155982, 102.336218)

How do I set the longitude and latitude (2.155982, 102.336218) to the button and then pass it and been grab by the map page so I just need multiple button with a different longitude and latitude value?

Button code

```
button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Bikanbakar);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          Intent intent = new Intent(melaka.this,MapsActivity.class);
                                          startActivity(intent);

                                      }
                                  }
        );
```

Maps Code

```
 private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(2.155982, 102.336218);

        //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Current Location"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .title("Ikan Bakar Parameswara");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
```